# Making a queue in c

Tags: c

I'm having trouble trying to create a queue. My program runs certain commands but they can only run if some requirements are completed. I created child processes to run those commands and when one command ends the information is updated and some other command can run or not. Do you have any suggestion?
This is what I´m trying to do:

```
char * queque[1024]; 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
int start = canstart();  //returns 1 if can start and 0 if not
char *input[1024]; 
strcat(input, "teste.mp3");
char *output[1024]; 
strcat(output, "output.mp3");
char *executable = {./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-tempo-double,NULL};
if(start==1){

if(!fork()){
   int input_f;
   if ((input_f = open(input, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
          perror("Error opening input file")
          return -1;
          }
   dup2(input_f, 0);
   close(input_f);
                    
   int output_f;
   if ((output_f = open(output, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
         perror("Error creating output file");
         return -1;
         }

   dup2(output_f, 1);
   close(output_f);

   execvp(*executable, executable);
   _exit(0);
   }
   
  }else{strcat(queque,argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: when i add the argv[1] to the queque, then when the child ends i want to verify if any of the elements in queque can start or not.

Comment: If you have more details to add, put them in the question, not comments. And note the correct spelling of "queue"

Comment: `strcat(queque,argv[1])` the arguments to `strcat` have to be strings. `queque` is an array of strings, not a string.

Comment: But you've never initialized any of the elements of the array.

Comment: The first argument to `execvp()` must be a string. `argv[1]` is a string, `*argv[1]` is the first character of that string.

Comment: You should be getting lots of warnings about incorrect argument types from this code. Don't ignore them, fix them.

Comment: @Barmar in each position of the queque i want to save the code to run

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please show an example of the arguments to the program and what it should do with them.

Comment: the code above is just an exemple for what i need to do. I have a project and i need to implement one queque. I can't put here the full project

Comment: And while you're editing the question, please clean up the code indentation.

Comment: I never asked for the full project. Just give an example of what this program is supposed to do.

Comment: @Barmar the argv[1] in this case can be: ./bin/aurrasd-filters/aurrasd-tempo-double

Comment: `queue[current_index++] = argv[1];`